# Is there a way to automatically press the okay button on a Google App Script msgBox?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that props a user to scan a bar code then it finds the barcode in a sheet and marks the date next to it. The scanner that I use enters the value for the barcode and then an enter character so that if I am scanning multiple barcodes the input would look like:

```
123456
123456
123456
```

without me having to press any buttons. I would like to be able to just scan multiple items without having to press 'OK' every time. However Google Apps sheets does not accept enter as okay, is there a way to do this?

Here is a sample of my code:

```js
    var barCodeId = Browser.inputBox('Scan Barcode', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (barCodeId != 'cancel'){
      try{     
        sheet.createTextFinder(barCodeId).findNext().offset(0, 15).activate().setValue(date);
        var location = '892 ' + Browser.inputBox('Enter Location');
        //used to check if the item is in the same place and colors the tile if not
        colorLocation(location)
      }
      //creates a sheet and lists items not on inventory
      catch(error){
        var nonSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Not on Inventory");
        if (nonSheet == null){
          nonSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();
          nonSheet.setName("Not on Inventory"); 
          createTitle(nonSheet)
        }
          SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(nonSheet)
          var location = Browser.inputBox('Enter Location');
          fillInformation(barCodeId, location, date, nonSheet)
        }
    } else{
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this using Browser.inputBox().

Your best option to achieve this functionality is to use a custom [HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) interface displayed via [Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) in either a dialog window or a sidebar.  This will require some changes to your underlying workflow, but you have much more flexibility, as you can run client-side javascript on your form and take actions whenever you receive input from the scanner.